SQL Server Import wizard 64 bit error with truncation
I'm importing a 4.5 million row file from a SQL Server to another one for further analysis. The process stops every time there's a truncation error.
I use Notepad++ to go to the row and see where the problem is. If it's just a cell shift, I fix it, if not I delete the row, and start the import again. So far the error was once every 4-500 thousand rows.
I was able to get 3.2 million rows imported, but I keep getting these truncation error messages. I am sure that there must be a SQL command to tell SQL Server to skip those rows while importing so I don't have to start the import again every 2 hours.
I still have 1.5 million rows to import. How can I tell SQL Server to skip the row and go to the next one?
Or can I do it in Visual Studio? I used to work with SQL statement a very long time go, so I am quite a novice...

If you keep getting truncation errors then surely the problem is your column isn't wide enough, no?

If you're "content" with data lossz then out the data in a staging table with appropriate definitions and then filter out the data when you insert it into your production table.

*.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based
on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are too long or missing completely, i.e. column positions will vary.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data
format/shape, data types, cardinality, encoding, and enforce data quality.

Even with XML and an XSD, this won't stop the error the OP is seeing, @YitzhakKhabinsky .

That's strange, why would you have so much issue with a file, and why not just take a proper backup?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/validate-xml-with-the-xml-task?view=sql-server-ver16

XSD validation shows every single error, line in the file (position), and exact error. Please see it checking a link in my previous comment

I'm confused why you would ever use files like this to do such a transfer. Why not use Import/Export Wizard in SSMS or similar to do a straight copy?

I've been there with 300 million rows.  I wound up saying every column is nvarchar(max), just to get the dang import to finish.  Then I went through using SQL and cleaned up bad rows.  Then converted or made new columns to hold the final datatype+values (int, varchar(10), etc).
